# Spring boot web application can't find image in WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is my project content structure:

[image: this is my project content structure]

The spring boot applicaton, `InternalResourceViewResolver` is pointed to the jsp resource:

[image: spring boot applicaton]

This is the login.jsp, and the background tag can't load the image in WEB-INF/jsp/Image, but in spring boot application.java, I had pointed the resource. How can I get it?

[image: the login jsp]

Comment: A Spring Boot app is a jar not a war (at least I don't see anything that is making your boot application a war). I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/#_create_a_simple_web_application) and [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/).

Comment: the guide you suggest i had read.but i want to use spring boot to start my program,not tomcat.and i had find the solution sevral days,but get nothing!

Comment: Then I highly doubt you have actually read and done the guides. Both the guides use spring boot to start the application. Spring boot is what starts tomcat. BUt a Spring Boot application doesn't have a web-inf nor web.xml as that isn't used.

Comment: ok,i must have a wrong understanding about spring boot,put it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path of the image is relative to the URL, not relative to the location of the JSP.
Try putting the image here:
src/main/webapp/Images/LoginBg.jpg

Comment: oh,yeah.that's work.thank you.you have solve.and i have another question ,i ever read a blog that says can use below program:

`@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/my/dropbox");
    }
} `

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I understand that all static resources should be located in /resources/static or public location (as per Spring documentation) but it didn't work.

I implemented my own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("");
    }
}
```

Now it works. Hope it can help to somebody.